# Finding the middle element of Singly Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

Here is my code:

```
    public void findMiddlePos() {
    int pos = 1;
    Node pointerOne = first;
    Node pointerTwo = first;
    while(pointerOne.next.next != null) {
        pointerOne = pointerOne.next.next;
        pointerTwo = pointerTwo.next;
        pos++;
    }
    System.out.println("The middle element is : ");
    if((pos % 2) == 1)
        pointerTwo.printNode();
    else 
        pointerTwo.next.printNode();

}
```

Is it an efficient way? Also, I am doubtful about this line **while(pointerOne.next.next != null)**. Previously, I was just using this condition in while loop: **pointerOne.next != null**, but I was getting Null pointer exception so shifter to earlier one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Java programmer, so this merely regards the algorithm.

```
while(pointerOne.next.next != null) {
    pointerOne = pointerOne.next.next;
    pointerTwo = pointerTwo.next;
    pos++;
}
```

What happens if `pointerOne.next` is `null`? I'm guessing you'd need this:

```
while(pointerOne != null && pointerOne.next != null) {
```

I don't know if there is some shorthand for this in Java.

I also fail to see the purpose of the final `if`. Assume that you have a list with 3 elements. Then, after the loop, you'll have

```
pointerOne = first.next.next; // i.e., pointerOne = last
pointerTwo = first.next;
pos = 2;
```

So, `pointerTwo` points to the second (i.e., middle) element. But then your `if` will printout the successor of `pointerTwo`, which is the third element of a three-element list, so definitely not the middle one.

Lastly, I'd suggest using more descriptive names. For example, `ptrLast` and `ptrMiddle`, instead of `pointerOne` and `pointerTwo`. It makes your code more readable to others (which also includes you, after a few months).

One comment on your previous attempt:

> Is it an efficient way? Also, I am doubtful about this line **while(pointerOne.next.next != null)**. Previously, I was just using this condition in while loop: **pointerOne.next != null**, but I was getting Null pointer exception so shifter to earlier one.

If the length of your list is even, you'll get `pointerOne == null` at some point, so `pointerOne.next` will result in an error. But, similarly, if the length of your list is odd, you'll get `pointerOne.next == null` at some point, so `pointerOne.next.next` will result in an error.

Since you're jumping by two nodes at a time, you need to make sure that they are **both** non-null. Hence the condition I've put above.

Answer (score 0):

If you were getting a NPE with `pointerOne.next` and not `pointerOne.next.next` then something else is going on. You should not be able to get to `.next.next` without having a connection to `.next`, it is a "linked" list after all. Regarding the code supplied, the methodology used would find the center of an oddly sized list, but the current implementation is buggy as described in other posts. Furthermore, I would argue that an evenly sized list does not have a single center as would be indicated by the implementation provided.

Regarding middle position and assuming you have implemented this linked list yourself, you should internally manage a size variable as any good [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) would. Thus, you would know the overall size of the collection and could determine the middle index(s) and `.next` to it/them.

Comment: I have deliberately not used the size variable, in many tests questions it is not allowed.

Comment: As you said, Even list will not have a single center. But we have to pick one, I have removed my if condition. And now the algorithm picks the second number from the two middle numbers.